# How to view C++ template argument in watch window in VS2015

Tags: c++, templates, visual-studio-2015, watch

I am debugging some C++ code which contains some C++ templates with T as an template argument. I would like to see in watch (or on mouse over) what type is T.

When I add T to watch, it does not show the type. Is there a way to resolve T argument in debugger?

I can see the template arguments types on call stack. As the types are quite complex, the lines in the  he call stack is so long, that cannot fit my display. And very hard to read.

Is there a way to resolve T argument in debugger watch?

I use Visual Studio 2015 Update 3.

[image]

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Add `_First` or `_Last` to the watch widow, they are of type `_Iter`, and the resolved type will be displayed. I don't think there is any other way: at compile time _Iter is replaced by whatever type is used, so once the application is built there's no notice of the name _Iter anymore.

Comment: And what to do in cases where no instance of T is in source code?

Comment: Not really sure what you mean: when there is no instantiation, there's also no type to figure out? And in any case there actually is also no compiled source code so in the executable there's no trace of the class so also nothing to debug (just like with any non-template class or function)

Comment: and what about typeid(T) or some function result = someMagicFunction<T>()

Comment: Same strory. There is no variable of type T, so the only type info the compiler left in the object files is the full function type (i.e. someMagic<myactualType>) and it can show that in the call stack or in the disassembly view.